# Android: Getting extra empty file when creating logs with log4j2

Tags: java, android, logging, configuration, log4j2

I am getting an extra empty file when I try to get my logs from log4j2. The file name is "$(sys" and it contains absolutely nothing but it is created every time I run my program here is my java file where I log:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    int mHour = date.getHours();
    int mMinute = date.getMinutes();

    String filenameWE = String.valueOf(mHour) + "_" + String.valueOf(mMinute)+"_WarErr";
    String filenameFull = String.valueOf(mHour) + "_" + String.valueOf(mMinute)+"_Full_Log";

    System.setProperty("WarErrFilename", filenameWE);
    System.setProperty("FullLogFilename", filenameFull);

    LoggerContext ctx =  (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.reconfigure();

    logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
    logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
    logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
    logger.info("Hello world - info log");
    logger.info("Hello world - info log");
    logger.info("Hello world - info log");

    logger.warn("Hello world - warn log");        
    logger.warn("I farted!");
    logger.error("Hello world - error log");
    logger.error("Error please insert brain!");
    logger.error("Error cant poop!");
}
```

And my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/${date:yyyy}/${date:MM}/${date:dd}/${sys:WarErrFilename}.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Filters>
    </File>
    <File name="Technical"
          fileName="logs/${date:yyyy}/${date:MM}/${date:dd}/${sys:FullLogFilename}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    </File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Technical"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>  
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Do both two (MyFile & Technical) logfiles exist? This would help narrow down your error.

Comment: Yes the 2 files do exist. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config is missing the outer `<Configuration>` element that your `<Appenders>` and `<Loggers>` must be nested in. Take a look at the manual for an example.

Also, why not set the system properties before getting the Logger from the LogManager?

Comment: if you take a closer look at the code I provided, the `<Configuration>` element is there

Comment: Oh I see. On my phone it's hidden behind the <?xml...?> element. But I don't see a closing tag...

Comment: its there I just need to edit it else it wont compile and produce any result now would it? :) I will fix it up in sec.

Comment: Now it should all be fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting the necessary system properties _before_ initializing Log4j by getting the first Logger from the LogManager? Then you don't need to reconfigure. (There may be a bug in the reconfigure logic...)

Comment: OH GOD!! Such an obvious solution. Thanks a lot man you where right! I needed to initialize the `LogManager` after the reconfiguration.